# Reading sounds from assets folder for playnig in soundpool

Tags: java, android

I want to read my sounds from assets, it is a game tat play a sound to guess.
now my sounds are in raw folder and now I want to read them from asset.
i google it and also I found some code that works correctly but I can just read the first sound.

take a look in my code:

here i read from raw:

```
 int sound_id = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(SoundFile, "raw",
                mContext.getPackageName());
        soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                loaded = true;
            }
        });
        soundID = soundPool.load(this, sound_id, 1);
```

and here i use the code but it just play my first sound

```
   private static void initiate() {
    XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;
    try {
        pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();

        XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();

        InputStream in_s = G.context.getAssets().open("temp.xml");
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(in_s, null);
        routpic.parseXML(parser);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("EROR", "nabod");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("EROR", "nabod");

    }
    array_audio.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < routpic.names.size(); i++) {
        array_audio.add(routpic.names.get(i));
        Log.i("LOG2", "" + routpic.names.get(i));
    }


}
private void play(int index) {
    mediaPlayer.release();
    index++;
    index=soundID;
    String s = "mp3/a" + index + ".mp3";
    //Resources resources = getResources();

    AssetFileDescriptor afd;
    try {
        afd = getAssets().openFd(s);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and in my assets :

```
 <mp3>
    <name>1</name>
</mp3>
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer I cancel the soundpool and I use from madiapalayer.
and with this way I read my musics from asset folder.
I put my music in the mp3 folder like here:

```
  AssetFileDescriptor afd;
        try {
            afd = getAssets().openFd("mp3/" + "a" + lvl + ".mp3");
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            //mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and after it , I start my mediapalayer easily.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

variables

```
private SoundPool soundPool;
private AssetFileDescriptor afd;
```

put this code in onCreate your activity or fragments

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();
        soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                .setMaxStreams(1)
                .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                .build();
} else {
   soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
}
soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
            soundPool.play(sampleId, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);
        }
});
```

load and play mp3 file from assets folder

```
try {
  afd = getResources().getAssets().openFd("mp3/ba.mp3");
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
soundPool.load(afd, 1);
```

load and play mp3 file from raw directory

```
//activity
soundPool.load(this, R.raw.ba, 1);
//or fragments
soundPool.load(getActivity(), R.raw.ba, 1);
```

Comment: The only issue I'm having with it is how to get the sampleId variable. AFAIK, it comes from the load, but the issue is that loading is done below setting the onLoadCompleteListener